# : php mysql search by postcode used to work on our website, but now it returns error:that postcode was not recognized"

Tags: php, mysql

Our site has a store search and it worked fine but somehow, sometime ago it started returning an error that reads "that postcode was not recognized" I am not sure which information to copy and paste here to show you, as I am too new to php and mysql. Can anybody help me? I am in a time crunch. 
Here is the php page code:

```
  <?php
/**
 * The template used for displaying page content in dealersearch-page.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */

/*==============================================================================
Application: Easy Postcode Finder
Author: Leon Chevalier
Version: V1.0
Date: 16th December 2007
URL: http://aciddrop.com/2007/12/17/quick-easy-and-free-nearest-store-postcodezip-finder/

alt: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/** 
* The curl class
*/  


/*
HOW TO UPDATE!!!
?update=all
?update=fixzeros
?update=new
*/

define('TOTAL_SEARCHED', 10);

class curl {

    /** 
    * COnstructor
    */  
    function curl() {



    }

    function init_curl($ch,$url,$postfields=null,$follow=null,$cookie=null,$referer=null) {

        // Set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        // Enable Post
        if($postfields) {
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        }

        if($follow) {
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );      
        }

        if($referer) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        }

        //Enable SSL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');

        //Return results as string
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        return $ch;

    } // end function


    /*
    Grabs a page
    */

    function get_page($options) {

    //Set options
    foreach($options AS $key=>$value) {
    $$key = $value; 
    }   

        $ch = curl_init();      
        $ch = $this->init_curl($ch,$url,$postfields,$follow,$cookie);
        $page = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $page;


    }


} // end class

/**
 * A simple wrapper for db functions
 *
 */
class db_custom {

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * A simple wrapper for database functions
     *
     */ 
    function db_custom()    {

    // database configuration
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "codaonline";
    $pass = "***********";
    $db = "codaonline"; 

    // open database connection
    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
    // select database
    mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");


    }

    ###############################################
    ## Updates an array of fields and values
    ## and reurn the resulting ID
    ###############################################
    function quick_update($database,$fields,$values,$wherearray) {
    //Variables
    $num_array = count($values);
    //Format NULL
    $values = str_replace("'NULL'","NULL",$values);
    //Write query
    $query = "UPDATE `$database` SET ";
    foreach ($fields AS $key=>$value) {
    $count++;
    $query .= " $fields[$key] = '$values[$key]'";
    if ($count <> $num_array) { $query .= ","; }
    }
    //Create where
    foreach ($wherearray AS $key=>$value) {
    $counterv++;
        $query_chk .= "$key = '" . trim($value) . "'";

            if ($counterv != count($wherearray)) {
            $query_chk .= " AND ";
            }
    }

    $query .= " WHERE $query_chk";
    $query = str_replace("'`","",$query);
    $query = str_replace("`'","",$query);


    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_affected_rows();
    return $rows;
    }


    ######################################################
    # Execute row
    # runs query and gets row back
    ######################################################
    function executeRow($query__ER,$type=null) {
    $result__ER = mysql_query($query__ER) or die ("Error in query: $query__ER. " . mysql_error());
        if($result__ER != 1) {
            if($type!="array") {
            $row__ER = mysql_fetch_object($result__ER);
            } else {
            $row__ER = mysql_fetch_assoc($result__ER);
            }
        return $row__ER;        
        }
    }

    ######################################################
    # Connects to the database and returns the 
    # results in an array
    ######################################################

    function executeQuery($query,$func=null,$type="") {

        //Get the table name from the query
        preg_match("/SELECT(.*)FROM( )([A-z_]+)/i",$query,$matches);
        $table_name = $matches[3];

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $columns = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($rows > 0) { // Only proceed if we have a result

        mysql_data_seek($result,0);
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                foreach ($columns As $key=>$value) {


                            //Run any extra functions that have been sent over
                            if(is_array($func)) {           
                                foreach ($func AS $Fkey=>$Fvalue) {                     
                                $row[$key] = $this->$Fvalue($row[$key],$key,$table_name);               
                                } // end FE         
                            } // end IF

                                if($type == "object") {
                                //echo $key . "  "  . $row[$key] . "\n";
                                $tmp->$key = $row[$key];                
                                } else {
                                $tmp[$key] = $row[$key];
                                }

                }// end for each

                    $results[] = $tmp;
                    unset($tmp);
            } //end while 

        $final_result['result'] = $results;
        $final_result['rows'] = mysql_num_rows($result);        
        } else {
        $final_result['rows'] = 0;      
        }// end if

    return $final_result;

    } // end function


}

/**
 * A postcode finder class
 *
 */
class postcode_finder {

    /**
    * Constructor
    *
    */
    function postcode_finder($array) {

        if(is_array($array)) {
            foreach($array AS $key=>$value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }   

        //DO stuff

    }

    /**
    * Setup database tables and insert lat longs
    *
    */  
    function setup()
    {
        //DONT EXECUTE THE 2 FUNCTION BELOW, SINCE THE DB IS ALREADY SET UP
        //$this->create_store_table();
        //$this->insert_example_stores();

        $this->update_lat_lngs();   
    }

    /**
    * Makes an example store table
    *
    */  
    function create_store_table()
    {
        //Create table
        $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
          `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          `name` varchar(75) NOT NULL default '',
          `address` text NOT NULL,
          `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
          `lat` double NOT NULL default '0',
          `lng` double NOT NULL default '0',
          `domain` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
          PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM";
        $this->db->executeRow($query);  
    }

    /**
    * Insert some example stores
    *
    */  
    function insert_example_stores()
    {
        //for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
            $query = "
            INSERT INTO `store` (`name` , `address` , `postcode`, `domain`) 
            VALUES (
            'Waterloo Station', 'Lambeth, London', '90277', 'com'
            ), (
            'Gatwick Airport ', 'South Terminal, Gatwick', 'RH6', 'co.uk'
            ), (
            'Edinburgh Waverley Railway Station ', 'Network Rail, Room 255, North Block, Edinburgh', 'EH1 1BB', 'co.uk'
            ), (
            'Beverly Hills', 'California', '90210', 'com'
            ), (
            'Penn Station ', '17 W 32nd St New York', '10001', 'com'
            ), (
            'La Sagrada Familia', 'Barcelona', '08013', 'es'
            ), (
            'FC Bayern Munchen', 'Sabener Str. 51, Munchen, Germany ', '81547', 'de'
            )       
            ";

            $this->db->executeRow($query);  
        //}
    }

    /**
    * Update lat lngs
    *
    */  
    function update_lat_lngs()
    {       
        //Get the list of stores
        //$query = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE `lat` = ''";
        if($_GET['update'] == "new")
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE `lat` IS NULL";
        }
        else if($_GET['update'] == "fixzeros")
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE `lat` = '0.000000'";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM store";
        }
        $stores = $this->db->executeQuery($query);
        $stores = $stores['result'];

        //Run through stores and get lat / lng
        foreach($stores AS $store) {

            $latlng = $this->get_lat_long($store['postcode'],$store['domain']);

            //Update store with its lat lng
            $this->db->quick_update("store",
                                    array('lat','lng'),
                                    array($latlng['lat'],$latlng['lng']),
                                    array('id'=>$store['id'])
                                    );
        }
    }

    /**
    * Returns a lat / long of a given postcode
    *
    */  
    function get_lat_long($postcode,$domain=null) {

        if(!$domain) {
            $domain = "com";
        }

        $url = "http://maps.google." . $domain . "/maps/geo?q=" . urlencode($postcode) . "&output=json&key=ABQIAAAAd68ReBKRz0DIUqnh0urYdhR0Q3-qVDTU2G-tuQrQTRhYanhS-xTuF2SEKlLS-kmZKBwQN9ukjwTT_A";

        $json = $this->curl->get_page(array("url"=>$url));

        $store_data = json_decode(str_replace("&quot;","\"",htmlentities($json))); //Take care of accents

        $lng = $store_data->Placemark[0]->Point->coordinates[0];            
        $lat = $store_data->Placemark[0]->Point->coordinates[1];

            //Return
            if($lng && $lat) {

                return array('lat'=>$lat,
                             'lng'=>$lng
                             );

            } else {

                return false;

            }

    }


    /**
    * Get a list of our stores, sorted by distance to this postcode
    *
    */  
    function get_stores_list($postcode) {

        //If it's a UK postcode then format correctly
        $postcode = $this->checkPostcode($postcode);

        $latlng = $this->get_lat_long($postcode);

        if(!$latlng) { //Unrecognised postcode
        return false;
        }

        $latitude = $latlng['lat'];
        $longitude = $latlng['lng'];        
//      print_r($latlng);

        $query = "SELECT *,
                    (((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))
                    +cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) 
                    * cos(((".$longitude."- `lng`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) 
                    as distance 
                        FROM `store`
                        ORDER BY distance ASC
                        LIMIT 0,".TOTAL_SEARCHED;
        $stores = $this->db->executeQuery($query);
        $stores = $stores['result'];            

        return $stores;

    }


    /**
    * Checks whether supplied postcode is a valid UK postcode
    */
    function checkPostcode($toCheck) {

      $orig = $toCheck;

      // Permitted letters depend upon their position in the postcode.
      $alpha1 = "[abcdefghijklmnoprstuwyz]";                          // Character 1
      $alpha2 = "[abcdefghklmnopqrstuvwxy]";                          // Character 2
      $alpha3 = "[abcdefghjkstuw]";                                   // Character 3
      $alpha4 = "[abehmnprvwxy]";                                     // Character 4
      $alpha5 = "[abdefghjlnpqrstuwxyz]";                             // Character 5

      // Expression for postcodes: AN NAA, ANN NAA, AAN NAA, and AANN NAA
      $pcexp[0] = '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

      // Expression for postcodes: ANA NAA
      $pcexp[1] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}[0-9]{1}'.$alpha3.'{1})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

      // Expression for postcodes: AANA NAA
      $pcexp[2] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'[0-9]{1}'.$alpha4.')([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

      // Exception for the special postcode GIR 0AA
      $pcexp[3] =  '^(gir)(0aa)$';

      // Standard BFPO numbers
      $pcexp[4] = '^(bfpo)([0-9]{1,4})$';

      // c/o BFPO numbers
      $pcexp[5] = '^(bfpo)(c\/o[0-9]{1,3})$';

      // Load up the string to check, converting into lowercase and removing spaces
      $postcode = strtolower($toCheck);
      $postcode = str_replace (' ', '', $postcode);

      // Assume we are not going to find a valid postcode
      $valid = false;

      // Check the string against the six types of postcodes
      foreach ($pcexp as $regexp) {

        if (ereg($regexp,$postcode, $matches)) {

          // Load new postcode back into the form element  
          $toCheck = strtoupper ($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches [2]);

          // Take account of the special BFPO c/o format
          $toCheck = ereg_replace ('C\/O', 'c/o ', $toCheck);

          // Remember that we have found that the code is valid and break from loop
          $valid = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      // Return with the reformatted valid postcode in uppercase if the postcode was 
      // valid
      if ($valid){
      return $toCheck;
      } else {
      $this->non_standard_postcode = true;
      return $orig;
      };

    }   


}

//If we have a post
if($_POST['postcode'])
{ 
    //Start database class
    $db = new db_custom();
    $curl = new curl();
    $finder = new postcode_finder(array('db'=>$db, 'curl'=>$curl));                       
    $stores = $finder->get_stores_list($_POST['postcode']);                       
}

if($_GET['update'])
{
    $db = new db_custom();
    $curl = new curl();
    $finder = new postcode_finder(array('db'=>$db, 'curl'=>$curl));                       
    $finder->setup();
}

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <hr>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>







        <!-- BEGIN SEARCH FORMATTING -->                                                                  
        <form action="#results" method="post" class="bigsearchform">
            <div class="bigsearch">
                Enter your ZIP or City and press Enter.<br/>
                For Example: "90505" or "Montclair, CA"
                <div>
                    <input class="searchbox" type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $_POST['postcode']; ?>" placeholder="Enter your ZIP or City">
                    <input class="search-img" type="image" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/bigsearch.png" value="Submit" alt="Submit">
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="results"></div>        
        <?php if($_GET['update']) { ?>  
            <h2 style="background-color:padding:2px">Database Updated</h2>                              
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ($_POST['postcode']) { ?>
            <?php if($stores) { ?>
                <h2>The following <?php //echo TOTAL_SEARCHED; ?> Installing Dealers were found near to you</h2>

                <?php foreach($stores as $store) { ?>
                <div class="dealer">
                    <div class="company"><?php echo $store['name']; ?> <span>is <span style="background-color:#ffffcc"><?php echo number_format($store['distance'],2); ?></span> miles from you</span></div>

                    <div class="contact">
                        <?php echo $store['contact']; ?>
                        <?php if($store['email'] != '') { ?>
                            (<a href="mailto:<?php echo $store['email']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $store['email']; ?></a>)
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="map"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=<?php echo $store['address']; ?> <?php echo $store['city']; ?> <?php echo $store['state']; ?> <?php echo $store['postcode']; ?>&size=320x150&zoom=14&sensor=false" width="320" height="150" /></div>

                    <div class="on-right">
                        <div class="address"><?php echo $store['address'] . ' ' . $store['address2']; ?><br/>
                        <?php echo $store['city']; ?>, <?php echo $store['state']; ?> <?php echo $store['postcode']; ?></div>

                        <div class="phonefax">Phone: <?php echo $store['phone']; ?><br />
                        Fax: <?php if($store['fax'] != '') echo $store['fax']; else echo "N/A"; ?></div>

                        <?php if($store['url'] != '') { ?>
                            <div class="url"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/link.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Website Link" /> <a href="<?php echo $store['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $store['url']; ?></a></div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="otherinfo">License #: <?php echo $store['license']; ?> &mdash; <?php echo $store['keybusiness']; ?></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <h2>That postcode was not recognized</h2>               
            <?php } ?>  
        <?php } ?>







    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

I am not sure what other files you need? The website is codaonline.org

Comment: I hope that isn't your actual database password. If so please change it on your server right away.

Comment: Honestly, your best bet is to probably talk to whomever put your site together, or hire an on site developer.  Because troubleshooting this will require more than looking at a single file.  There will need to be testing (is it choking on ALL addresses or just some?), the ability to check if the database is running and not compromised, etc.

Comment: Find In Files > Select directory for files to scan > Scan for the string "that postcode was not recognized" > Read the above and blow lines of code to find the condition which caused this `user error` to be defined & fix

Comment: Far too much code. This is too vague to debug successfully on [so]. My best suggestion - find a programmer who can spend time on it.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon: It's worse than that. Their MySQL service is exposed to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Lets route through this error.

```
        <?php } else { ?>
            <h2>That postcode was not recognized</h2>               
        <?php } ?>
```

Is found, so if we follow the first closing bracket. We will be shown:

```
        <?php if($stores) { ?>
```

So $stores is defined in:

```
if($_POST['postcode'])
{ 
    //Start database class
    $db = new db_custom();
    $curl = new curl();
    $finder = new postcode_finder(array('db'=>$db, 'curl'=>$curl));                       
    $stores = $finder->get_stores_list($_POST['postcode']);                       
}
```

so, i've started your searching. It's up to you to see why your condition is failing.

I would also suggest taking a look at `isset()` instead of `if ($var)`

---

To sum it up, my guess is that `$stores` is not even set or is returning false, hence falling into the `else` clause in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `get_lat_long` function:

```
$url = "http://maps.google." . $domain . "/maps/geo?q=" . urlencode($postcode) . "&output=json&key=ABQIAAAAd68ReBKRz0DIUqnh0urYdhR0Q3-qVDTU2G-tuQrQTRhYanhS-xTuF2SEKlLS-kmZKBwQN9ukjwTT_A";
```

Now [try that URL yourself](https://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Washington,%20DC&output=json&key=ABQIAAAAd68ReBKRz0DIUqnh0urYdhR0Q3-qVDTU2G-tuQrQTRhYanhS-xTuF2SEKlLS-kmZKBwQN9ukjwTT_A). I get

> ## Google
>
> ## We're sorry...
>
> ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

Evidently, that URL is not supposed to be used by others as an API. Google noticed and blocked you. You'll have to find an API *you're actually allowed to use* to get latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 0):

The line "This postcode was not recognized" will show up if `$stores` is false.

This is the line that defines it:

```
$stores = $finder->get_stores_list($_POST['postcode']);
```

I'd put an `echo` command next to the query in the get_stores_list function and see if the query is ok, and then run it in the database. You'll have to narrow the matter down a bit for more assistance from the community.

Answer (score 0):

The problem

> The Geocoding API v2 has been turned down on September 9th, 2013. The
>   Geocoding API v3 should be used now.

The solution

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/